# Visual Studio 2015 Community Setup Failed

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio

I began receiving this message three days ago when I started VS 2015 Community edition:
[image]

I am logged in and I do have a Visual Studio account.  Most of my searches online indicate that I should see a button that allows me to renew my license, but it is not there.  I have tried to repair this installation and have tried to uninstall it, but there is no option to repair or uninstall under Control Panel > Uninstall a program. The only option is change:
[image]

When select Change or try to run vs_community_ENU.exe /uninstall /force from the command prompt, I get this message:

[image]

In summary, I cannot repair, uninstall or reinstall Community 2015. Do you have any suggestions on how to restore my VS 2015 Community edition to working order?

Comment: The reason you cannot renew the license is because your using a preview version of Visual Studio 2015.  *You basically never installed the final version.*

Comment: Is there a preview version of VS 2015 Community?  I assumed that the Community edition did not have a license because it was free.  I didn't use it for about 4 days; before that time I did not receive any prompts saying that my license would expire in X days.

Comment: Yes; 8 months ago there was a preview edition;  The current version is `Visual Studio 2015 Update 1`

Comment: @blueshift your first screenshot clearly says "prelease software"

Comment: @chuex I didn't install the pre-release or preview versio of VS 2015, so I have no idea why it is listed as pre-release in the screenshot above.  In the end I had to reinstall Windows and then install VS 2015 Community again.